Application crashes in Android 14 devices in ServiceCompat.startForeground() function
I am trying to make an android application that keeps recording videos even when the user leaves the app ( foreground service) . I declared all the permissions as per the documentation in the Manifest files and I granted all the in-use permissions. After running the App using an Android 14 level device the app crashes at ServiceCompat.startForeground() with the following exception:

java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type microphone callerApp=ProcessRecord{25db602 15445:com.nerovero.camerago/u0a1030} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE] any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD, android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_MEDIA_OUTPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_TUNER_AUDIO_INPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION_OUTPUT, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO]  and the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission

Below you can find the VideoRecordingService class  and the Manifest file:
VideoRecordingService:
import android.Manifest
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.content.pm.ServiceInfo
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.camera.core.Camera
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.video.MediaStoreOutputOptions
import androidx.camera.video.Quality
import androidx.camera.video.QualitySelector
import androidx.camera.video.Recorder
import androidx.camera.video.Recording
import androidx.camera.video.VideoCapture
import androidx.camera.video.VideoRecordEvent
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleService
import com.nerovero.camerago.CameraActivity.Companion.vQuality
import java.io.File

class VideoRecordingService : LifecycleService() {
    private val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
    private var cameraSelector = CameraActivity.cameraSelector

    //Initialize the following
    private lateinit var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider
    private lateinit var videoCapture: VideoCapture<Recorder>
    private lateinit var recording: Recording
    private lateinit var camera: Camera

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startCameraX()
        // Log.e("logo", "onCreate() from VideoRecordingService is called")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

        // Log.e("logo", "onStartCommand() from VideoRecordingService is called")
        val audioPermission =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
        val cameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        if ((audioPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (cameraPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            //this permission just is just for debugging remove it later on and add it in the intent of calling the
            // foreground service
            Log.e("logo", "the audio & camera permissions are already granted from the CameraActivity")
            //this permission check is subject to removal if I found a solution for the Android 14
            startForegroundService()
        } else {
            Log.e("logo", "the audio & camera permissions are not  granted from the CameraActivity")
        }

        // startRecordingVideo()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun startForegroundService() {
        // Log.e("logo", "startForegroundService() from VideoRecordingService is called")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            //try to use resources here
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                "video_recording_service",
                "Video Recording Service",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "video_recording_service")
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.video_recording))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.video_recording_in_progress))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.recording_on)
            .build()

        ServiceCompat.startForeground(
            this,
            1,
            notification,
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                // I just added ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE
                ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CAMERA or ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE
            } else {
                0
            }
        )

        //Log.e("logo", "the end of startForegroundService()")
        // startForeground(1, notification)
    }

    private fun startRecordingVideo() {
        Log.e("logo", "startRecordingVideo() is called ")
        val name: String = System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ""
        val fileName = "camerago_$name.mp4"
        val pathValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                put(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator +
                            getString(R.string.app_name)
                )
            }
        }

        // camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector)
        //initializeCamera()

        val mediaStoreOutputOptions =
            MediaStoreOutputOptions.Builder(contentResolver, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                .setContentValues(pathValues).build()

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return
        }
        recording = videoCapture.output
            .prepareRecording(this, mediaStoreOutputOptions)
            .withAudioEnabled()
            .start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)) { videoRecordEvent ->
                when (videoRecordEvent) {
                    is VideoRecordEvent.Start -> {
                        Log.e("logo", "VideoRecordEvent.Start from VideoRecordingService")
                    }

                    is VideoRecordEvent.Finalize -> {
                        Log.e("logo", "VideoRecordEvent.Finalize from VideoRecordingService ")
                        cameraProvider.unbind(videoCapture)
                        //I add this code below cause if i don't fdo it the app will crash
                        //saying a recording is already in progress
                        //....................
                        // startCameraX()
                        //.........................................
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        //this function should be moved to the end of the code
        recording.stop()
    }

    //this is an after code section if it is reliable integrate it to the main code
    //activating the cameraX
    private fun startCameraX() {
        val cameraProviderListenableFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(applicationContext) //maybe "this" is better

        cameraProviderListenableFuture.addListener({
            try {
                cameraProvider = cameraProviderListenableFuture.get()
                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector)
                initializeCamera()
                startRecordingVideo()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    //Initialization of the camera
    private fun initializeCamera() {
        try {
            //check the settings
            //initialization of the videoCapture through recorder
            try {
                val recorder =
                    Recorder.Builder().setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(vQuality)).build()
                videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                val recorder =
                    Recorder.Builder().setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.HIGHEST))
                        .build()
                videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)
            }
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, videoCapture)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

AndroidManifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--implementation of a file provider in order to be able to share the video to other platforms-->
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.nerovero.camerago.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <!--check whether enabled attribute is necessary in the service or not   -->
        <service
            android:name=".VideoRecordingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="camera|microphone"
            tools:node="merge" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PreviewActivity"
            android:exported="true">

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".CameraActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

I tried to modify in the service attributes in the Manifest file but it does not work.

"and the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission" -- how are you starting the service?

I think the app is in the eligible state to access the foreground only permission.
here's how I am calling the service :
if (Utilities.hasPermissions(this)) {
startService(Intent(this, VideoRecordingService::class.java))
} else {
Utilities.requestPermissions(this)
}

Call startForegroundService(), not startService().

The same thing . it crashes even with startForegroundService() . FYI the app works very well on devices running Android 11 and Higher ( expect Android 14 )

I found the issue: the reason is that in Android 14 we cannot call a foreground service from the background . Therefore I made a workaround and instead of trying to launch the video recording from the onStop() method of the CameraActivity I launch the video recording directly from the service while the CameraActivity  is still there.
